# Inner div should be displayed in front of outer div

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following code and would like the inner div with the class: escaping-container to be displayed in front of the outer div with the class container.

The inner div has bigger height setting than the outer div. So a part of it is cut off.

Also the part that is being cut of by outer div must be displayed.

```
<style type="text/css">

div.container{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

div.escaping-container{
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
  background-color:red;
}

</style>

<div class ="container">
  <div class="escaping-container"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to get this done by setting the z-index, but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties? If not, try removing them.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the overflow settings are necessary.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/28RWW/.  what is not working here?

Comment: What you're asking for is the exact opposite of what overflow: hidden/scroll are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Im afraid your question is a contradiction.  If you want the inner div to be visible, you must remove the overflow-x and overflow-y css statements.

Answer (score 2):

if the overflow settings are necessary
try this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/59nGZ/

css:

```
div.container{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
}

div.escaping-container{
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to position the inner `<div>` outside the parent with `overflow` set to scroll, hidden or auto. To be able to do so you either need to change your markup, or remove the `overflow`-properties from your CSS.